# create custom attribute in ad lds not in ad ds

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, apacheds, adlds

I just need to have a custom attribute "gender" in user class in **ADLDS** not in **ADDS** I have surveyed many articles and I have successfully able to have custom attribute in **ADDS** user class using this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBkQlTUsXww

but that way doesn't show up custom attribute in **ADLDS** in the properties of CN=anyUser of class user

[image: this is ADSI Edit]

but shows custom attribute in the properties of CN=anyUser **ADDS**

[image: this is Active Directory Users and Computers]

I need to have gender attribute in **ADLDS**' user !!! what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by adding the custom attribute to the **person** class as well as to the **organizationalPerson** class. My custom attribute shows up after that in user properties.

But for the time being I have added my custom attribute in all relevant classes **person**, **organizationalPerson** and in **user** class.